# How to make Android Studio build Kotlin Multiplatform project for an iOS app using cworkspace file instead of an xcodeproj file

Tags: ios, xcode, android-studio, kotlin-multiplatform

How to make Android Studio build Kotlin Multiplatform project for an iOS app using cworkspace file instead of an xcodeproj file

Command line invocation:

`"/.../Xcode 14.3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild" -project /.../iosApp/**iosApp.xcodeproj** -scheme iosApp -configuration Debug OBJROOT=/.../build/ios SYMROOT=/.../build/ios -sdk iphonesimulator -arch arm64 -allowProvisioningDeviceRegistration -allowProvisioningUpdates`

How to make it use iosApp.cworkspace instead of an iosApp.xcodeproj?

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible to customize the build pipeline from AS yet besides the options given in the edit configuration. What's the advantage of using the cworkspace?

Comment: what is `cworkspace`? Did you mean `xcworkspace`?